# AngularJs remove dynamically created ng-models/ng-bind

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, model, ng-bind

I have dynamically created elements with dynamically generated ng-model names, like:

The following is a pseudo code.

```
$scope.arr = [];

//html
<input type="button" ng-click="addNewVariable()">


$scope.addNewVariable = function() {
    $scope.arr.push([]);
    //some code that results in DOM inputs that follow
}

//dynamically created dom html
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName1" value="">
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName2" value="">
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName3" value="">
```

Now on screen, I type some data to the inputs:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName1" value="a">
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName2" value="b">
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName3" value="c">
```

at this point I have:

```
//I intentionally do not save values to array,
//but save them to dynamically created scope variables
$scope.arr = [[],[],[]];//i do need this structure for other purposes.
```

and (most likely) in memory/scope:

```
$scope.myVariableName1 = "a";
$scope.myVariableName2 = "b";
$scope.myVariableName3 = "c";
```

now I remove these input elements, from array, using splice function:

```
$scope.removeArrayElements = function(removeIndex) {
    $scope.arr.splice(removeIndex, 1);
    //the same code as above earlier,
    //but this time it removes(automatically) the inputs from Dom
}

//dynamically removed dom html
(Deleted myVariableName1 - no longer in Dom.)
(Deleted myVariableName2 - no longer in Dom.)
(Deleted myVariableName3 - no longer in Dom.)
```

now then I create these inputs again.

But the resulting inputs DO KEEP the OLD values, like .

```
//dynamically created new dom html
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName1" value="a">
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName2" value="b">
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName3" value="c">
```

where I expect:

```
//dynamically created new dom html
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName1" value="">(empty value)
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName2" value="">(empty value)
<input type="text" ng-model="myVariableName3" value="">(empty value)
```

so the question is - how to remove the dynamically created ng-models/ng-data-bindings that are possibly kept in memory/scope?

Something like with `eval()` function:

```
$scope.removeArrayElements = function(removeIndex, removeMyNgModelName) {
    $scope.arr.splice(removeIndex, 1);
    //the same code as above earlier,
    //but this time it removes(automatically) the inputs from Dom

    //this is what my question is all about!
    $scope.{removeMyNgModelName}.remove();//myVariableName1, myVariableName2, myVariableName3
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to target property with variable name:

```
$scope.removeArrayElements = function(removeIndex, removeMyNgModelName) {
    $scope.arr.splice(removeIndex, 1);
    //the same code as above earlier,
    //but this time it removes(automatically) the inputs from Dom

    delete $scope['myVariableName' + removeIndex]; //myVariableName1, myVariableName2, myVariableName3
}
```

Comment: thank you for brackets info! with this, i can access value.
[code]
    alert($scope[remModel]);
[/code]

but this does not do the trick...

[code]
    $scope[remModel].remove();
[/code]

Comment: this does not work either: $scope[remModel].destroy(); //Please do not worry about model naming - i do make sure they properly match.

Comment: As a workaround, i did this: $scope[remModel] = ""; but i am afraid this wont destroy/remove the binding and is possibly a memory leak?

Comment: It should be `delete $scope['myVariableName' + removeIndex];`. Sorry didn't notice this mistake of me. Of course, there is no remove method.